# Yandex Maps Как закрасить весь мир?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Yandex Maps Как закрасить весь мир?
То есть нужно нарисовать прямоугольник размером во всеь мир.
Вот так не получается.

```
myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    // Геометрия = тип геометрии + координаты геообъекта.
    geometry: {
        // Тип геометрии - прямоугольник.
        type: 'Rectangle',
        // Координаты.
        coordinates: [[-179, -79],[179, 79]]
    },
    // Свойства.
    properties: {
        hintContent: 'Перетащи меня!',
        balloonContent: 'Прямоугольник 2'
    }
}, {
    // Опции.
    // Объект можно перетаскивать.
    draggable: true,
    // Цвет и прозрачность заливки.
    fillColor: '#ffff0022',
    // Цвет и прозрачность границ.
    strokeColor: '#3caa3c88',
    // Ширина линии.
    strokeWidth: 7
});
```

Comment: Захватить весь мир прямоугольником видимо не получится, прийдется захватывать частями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте квадратный полигон с промежуточными точками, чтобы он не "схлопывался".

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  map = new ymaps.Map('map', {center: [0,0], zoom:0});
  polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([[
    [-179, -79],
    [   0, -79],
    [+179, -79],
    [+179, +79],
    [   ,  +79],
    [-179, +79],
  ]]);
  map.geoObjects.add(polygon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
```